# How poetry knows my package is located in the src folder?

Tags: python, testing, python-poetry

I have a simple question.

I used to create a poetry project with my package at root.

```
project.toml
mypackage
  +- __init__.py
  +- mypackage.py
  +- test_mypackage.py
```

I recently moved my tests in another directory, so that the folder now looks like.

```
project.toml
src
  +- mypackage
      +- __init__.py
      +- mypackage.py
tests
  +- test_mypackage.py
```

Nothing changed for poetry which still work fine when I make `poetry build`. How does it search for the package root folder? Does it serach a folder with the package name in `project.toml`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Having a folder called `src` to contain the package code is just a pre-defined standard that `poetry` recognizes without being told. It works via the [`packages`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages) section in your project file, which by default scans for `mypackage` and `src/mypackage`. If you provide your own value, it will stop auto-detecting those two.

Answer (score 9):

As of Poetry ver 1.6.1, the following spec in pyproject.toml works

```
[tool.poetry]
packages = [{include = "mypackage", from="src"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that has source modules contained directly in a `src` directory, without a `my_package` directory, and where you want imports to look something like

```
from my_module import foo 
from utils import bar 
from constants import FOOBAR
```

instead of

```
from src.my_module import foo
from src.utils import bar
from src.constants import FOOBAR
```

You can do the following in your pyproject file:

```
packages = [{include = "*", from="src"}]
```